# PDFMake create Horizontal WaterMark ( not diagonial )

Tags: pdfmake

Hi :) ? I am new user of [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) library and i saw how to create a simple watermark like the below :

```
var docDefinition = {
    watermark: { text: "watermark", color: "gray", opacity: 0.3, bold: true, alignment: "right" },
    content: [

    ]
}
```

[image: brave_2019-09-03_15-13-42]

---

**What i need**

But how can i make the text of it be **horizontal instead of diagonal** ?  [Github Issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1801)

I want it to appear horizontal like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally from version [1.60](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/releases/tag/0.1.60) onwards we can do this like below :

```
var docDefinition = {
  watermark: { text: 'test watermark', angle: 70 },
  content: [
    '...'
  ]
};
```

You can find more on the documentation here

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source code they calculate the angle of the watermark on the basis of the page width and height:
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/2c02af7d364782c3d9fa43babfd07ca04b08321d/src/Renderer.js#L277

You can contribute to the package by adding this feature to overwrite the angle and creating a merge request for it?

But maybe you can solve your problem in another way. Can you show what you want to achieve with the horizontal watermark?

Comment: I added an image of how i want it , just to be horizontal that's it :) I am new to Javascript and i am trying to figure out how to implement that option of angle.

Comment: From version [1.60](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/releases/tag/0.1.60) we can do that :) . Added an answer below .